# Difference between timestamp() and dateTime() methods of the Blueprint class

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, timestamp

In Laravel, the `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint` class has two methods that I would like to know concretely the difference between them.

```
$table->dateTime()
```

and

```
$table->timestamp()
```

Both store a date in the same way visibly.
Someone to enlighten me?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

So the secret to this is understanding what exactly each does.

The `dateTime()` and `timestamp()` functions here in Laravel use different table columns.

`dateTime()` uses DATETIME as the DB column type.
`timestamp()` uses TIMESTAMP as the DB column type.

`DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` have a lot of similarities but the difference itself lies outside Laravel and more in MySQL.

Their major difference is the range. For DateTime its up to year `9999` while for timestamp its only up to year `2038`. Other differences include the amount of bytes needed to store each.

I found a nice article that clearly states the similarities and differences of both here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/difference-between-mysql-datetime-and-timestamp-datatypes/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 10):

`$table->dateTime()`
Create a new date-time column on the table. While on the other hand,
`$table->timestamp()`
Create a new timestamp column on the table.

If you have a problem identifying the difference between *timestamp* and *datetime*,

> DATETIME represents a date (as found in a calendar) and a time (as can be observed on a wall clock)

And,

> TIMESTAMP represents a well defined point in time. This could be very important if your application handles time zones. How long ago was '2010-09-01 16:31:00'? It depends on what timezone you're in.

Also, you can refer to [BluePrint Documentation](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html) for any inconveniences.

Answer (score 8):

`timestamp` and `dateTime` store a date (YYYY-MM-DD) and time (HH:MM:SS) together in a single field i.e. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.

The difference between the two is that `timestamp` can use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as its value, whenever the database record is updated.

`timestamp` has a limit of 1970-01-01 00:00:01 UTC to 2038-01-19 03:14:07 UTC `dateTime` has a range of 1000-01-01 00:00:00 to 9999-12-31 23:59:59 UTC

`timestamps` doesn't take an argument, it's a shortcut to add the `created_at` and `updated_at` timestamp fields to your database.

Comment: If I well understand, both functions are binded to MySQL if it is my DBMS ?

Comment: So in 2038 we're gonna have a Y2K bug again?